# Attaching files to GeoTIFF raster to open it in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, raster-dataset

I am trying to open a GeoTIFF raster, the dataset has xml file,tfw file, ovr and dbf file.

How do I attach those files to the raster and open it in ArcMap?

Comment: Just make sure all of the files are in the same folder, then add the .tiff using: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/adding-raster-data-to-a-map.htm

Comment: See: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-dataset-properties.htm , section "Files associated with raster datasets"